# Twig included template extending parent's block once

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is there a way to do this? I have a template which outputs one blog article.

Now, on **index** page I show 10 articles by including that template in **for** loop and on **show** page I only show one.

index:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {# some stylesheets here #}
{% endblock %}

{% for article in articles %}
        {% include VendorBundle:article.html.twig with { 'article': article } %}
{% endfor %}
```

show:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
      {# some stylesheets here #}
{% endblock %}

{% include VendorBundle:article.html.twig with { 'article': article } %}
```

Now is there a way to make **article.html.twig** add something to `{% block stylesheets %}` of templates that included it automatically? If it is possible, how do I prevent it from adding that 10 times when using `for` loop?

I'm trying to make my "fragment" templates (templates used for inclusion) define stylesheets that they use and make them "inject" those into page.

Comment: As I understand you are not trying to extend parent (article does not extent index or show?) block, but block of template that includes it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, article doesn't extend anything.

Comment: Its simply a page "fragment" if I may call it like that, it receives "article" object and "draws" it (tittle, content, images, tags, author, date etc).

Answer (score 18):

Did you try to use [**use**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html)?
Unfortunately I'm not completely sure if I got the question right but `{% use %}`wasn't mentioned here.

As I understand the question you've got your `article.html.twig` and include it in e.g. `index.html.twig`. Now you want to add something from `article.html.twig` into `index.html.twig`? Namely to the `{% stylesheets %}` block.

If I got how to use `{% use %}` you could maybe try it like this.

**article.html.twig**

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/css/article.css') }}" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block article %}
    {# whatever you do here #}
{% endblock %}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% use "VendorBundle:article.html.twig" with stylesheets as article_styles %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ block('article_styles') }}
    {# other styles here #}
{% endblock %}
{% for article in articles %}
        {% include VendorBundle:article.html.twig with { 'article': article } %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have not the chance to test it but the docu states a few very interesting things and it seems like this could be the way to do it.

> Horizontal reuse is an advanced Twig feature that is hardly ever needed in regular templates. It is mainly used by projects that need to make template blocks reusable without using inheritance.

I am rather new to stackoverflow. So please if my answer is completely useless could you just post a comment before down voting and I delete it?
However if it does help and there are just some errors in my example, also inform me and I'll fix it.

Comment: I've been looking at `include`, `extends`, `use`, etc. for too long... `use` actually works. However, three things: **1.** It seems to be impossible to extend a parent's block without modifying the parent (add `block('...')`). **2.** Your example (though not affecting me) will not work: `use` refuses to load templates with bodies, while `include` wouldn't make much sense here. Two templates would be needed then. **3.** Answers are never deleted for being wrong ;) . You'll get the bounty, but I'll wait - maybe someone else knows another solution. Thanks, however.

Comment: The example of the OP just confused me a bit. I didn't know how exactly he wants it to work (starting post and comments above are a bit contradictory) but your **2.** point came to my mind too. Is it possible to replace the include with another use of that template and just wrap the `{% for ... %}`loop in another block? **3.** I'm just a bit cautious because as I said I wasn't quite sure how the OP wants it to behave/work. In fact there are 7 days to go and on SO...there are geniuses on every corner :D

Comment: I see I'm not alone on this one. And I still haven't found a way to do this.

The most common use case for me would be "lazy loading" of stylesheets. So, we have "master template" which uses include on bunch of "fragment templates". Each fragment template can define it's own stylesheets which would then be appended to master's head.

Comment: @igorpan Same for me. Trying to include 'plugins' to the main template (sidebar modules etc.), which should append their styles and JS to the doc head and their body to the doc body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new block (not tested):

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% block stylesheets -%}
    {% block article_styles '' %}
{%- endblock %}

{% for ... -%}
    {% include VendorBundle:template.html.twig with {'article': article} %}
{%- endfor %}
```

```
{# template.html.twig #}
{% block article_styles -%}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel=stylesheet href=...>
{%- endblock %}

{# ... #}
```

Edit: Added `{{ parent() }}`, this will print every content the block already has.

Comment: Not really helpfull since if I go that way I could just add article's stylesheet directly into index.html.twig and show.html.twig, no point in making another block for it. I want article to do it by itself so when I have page with 10 included templates (articles, tags, sidebars, users etc etc) in itself I don't have to worry about them inside main template but allow each included template to define its CSS dependancies.

Comment: @igorpan ah, I have misunderstood your question. I have changed my answer.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, unfortunately, it doesn't work and throws an error: `Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden`.

Comment: When using blocks that extend other templates the child template must `{% extends '...' %}` the child template. See the [extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) documentation for more information.