# Influence the twig included file on parent

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110216/twig-included-template-extending-parents-block-once)

But i can not use {% use %}

for example:

```
{# file1.twig #}
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% block content %}content text{% endblock %}


{# main.twig #}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% for widget in widgets %}
    {% embed widget %}{% endembed %}
{% endfor %}
{% block js %}{% endblock %}


{# widget1.twig #}
{% block js %}
    script1
{% endblock %}

{# widget2.twig #}
{% block js %}
    script1
{% endblock %}
```

I want to be the result:

```
content text
script1
script2
```

I have a lot of files like file1.twig and widget1.twig

I can not use all the widgets in the all files.
Also, {{ parent() }} does not work for me
Is there another way?

Comment: why parent not working ? got error ?
and write your own post, instead of just a link, because if it is the same problem then it s a duplicate

Comment: Make use of the [deferred extension](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred#user-content-advanced-example)

Comment: parent not working because i do not want to change file1.twig, file2.twig and ...They are so many! 
This error occurs when i use parent in widgets:
Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden.

Because widget is not extended of main
@t-n-y

Comment: maybe it's me, but i don't understand a word of what you want to do